# Get href tags properly in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-3.4

I'm trying to get href links from a link. It looks like this

```
<div class="srTitleFull pcLink"><a style="display:block" name="000 Plus system requirements" title="000 Plus System Requirements" href="../games/index.php?g_id=21580&game=000 Plus">000 Plus</a></div><div class="srDescFull"><td>000+ is a bite-sized hardcore platformer. Its mini...</td></div><div class="srDateFull">Feb-10-2015</div>

<div class="srTitleFull pcLink"><a style="display:block" name="0RBITALIS system requirements" title="0RBITALIS System Requirements" href="../games/index.php?g_id=23521&game=0RBITALIS">0RBITALIS</a></div><div class="srDescFull"><td>0RBITALIS is a satellite launching simulator with ...</td></div><div class="srDateFull">May-28-2015</div><div class="srGenreFull">Sim</div><br /></div><div class="srRowFull"><div class="srTitleFull pcLink"><a style="display:block" name="10 Years After system requirements" title="10 Years After System Requirements" href="../games/index.php?g_id=22220&game=10 Years After">10 Years After</a></div>
```

So I tried to get those links like `../games/index.php?g_id=21580&game=000 Plus` and `../games/index.php?g_id=22220&game=10 Years After`. I tried this;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

r = urllib.request.Request('http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?year=2015',headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
rr = urllib.request.urlopen(r).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(rr)


url_list = []
for x in soup.find_all("div",attrs={'class':['srTitleFull']}):
   for y in soup.find_all("a", href = True):
        url_list.append(y['href'])
for x in url_list:
    print (x)
```

This get the links, but printing section goes forever. Probably because of 2 for loops, I'm adding links to the list more than once. I couldn't figure out how can I get those links one time and add them to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your nested loops is that you are using the `soup.find_all()` in both outer and inner loop asking `BeautifulSoup` to search the entire tree. You meant to use the `x` loop variable to search links inside, to make a "context-specific" search, so to say:

```
url_list = []
for x in soup.find_all("div",attrs={'class':['srTitleFull']}):
   for y in x.find_all("a", href = True):  # < FIX applied here
        url_list.append(y['href'])
```

---

**There is a better way.**

I'd use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate the links:

```
url_list = [a['href'] for a in soup.select(".srTitleFull > a")]
```

where `.srTitleFull > a` would match all `a` elements located directly inside elements with `srTitleFull` class.

This way you would not need a nested loop at all.

Comment: Under for loop or?

Comment: @GLHF nope, that's just all you need - you'll get a complete list of links.

Comment: Well, that was quick and elegant. I'm not experienced with BS and didn't know can use things like this. Nice answer thanks.

Comment: I have 1 more quick question

Comment: @GLHF sure, go ahead.

Comment: If I want to get `title` from `<div class="systemRequirementsHwBox` and `title` from `<a` tags, would `links1 = [a['title'] for a in soup.select(" .systemRequirementsHwBox > a")]` for the first one, and `links2 = [a['title'] for a in soup.select(" a")]` work?

Comment: To be more specific, check [this]([Inline Link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/18171871/)) please. I'm trying to get titles (game requirements) and then, `if "processor" in title`: print (title) for example

Comment: @GLHF okay, if I understand you correctly, you can just do `soup.select(".systemRequirementsHwBox[title*=processor]")`.

Comment: @GLHF yeah, may be this: `[a['title'] for a in soup.select(".systemRequirementsHwBox[title*=processor] a")]`?

Comment: I changed it to `print ([a['title'] for a in soup.select(".systemRequirementsHwBox a")])` this and it works now thanks for your help!